# How can I resize my fedora lvm partition to be larger with the root partition in the way?

Tags: fedora, partition, gparted

I have changed to Fedora Linux and shrunk my windows partition. I have unallocated space which I want Fedora to take up. I have looked other answers to questions like this and cannot find instructions for my use case. I have a picture of my drive right now. I also have a live USB ready.

From what I have read so far, I shouldn't touch the boot partition. Can someone give me instructions on how to get around the /boot? I will need to move it later as well to give more space to Fedora.

In short, how do I move the Fedora partition to before the boot ext4 partition and resize it?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I move the Fedora partition to before the boot ext4 partition and resize it?

The answer may be surprising: You don't have to do that.

Since you are using LVM and are **not** aiming to extend a non-LVM partition (i.e. `/boot`), you don't have to extend the existing PV. Instead, you can make a new partition out of the unallocated space, use `pvcreate` to make it a second LVM PV, then `vgextend` to *add it into your existing volume group*.

With LVM, your volume group may consist of one PV, or many PVs, on one or more disks; LVM does not care about that. All the PVs in a single VG will act together as a single pool of disk space. You can then extend or create new LVs freely, without needing to care where one PV ends and another begins. It will all be handled transparently by LVM.

First, use `gparted` or any tool you like to make that unallocated space into an usable partition. You should set its type ("flags" in `gparted`) as `lvm2 pv`, but strictly speaking you don't have to. I'll assume that it will be named `/dev/nvme0n1p7`.

Verify that the new partition is visible in `/proc/partitions`, indicating that the kernel has accepted the new partition table. If that did not happen, you may need to run `partprobe /dev/nvme0n1` and check again. If the partition is still not recognized by the kernel, you may need to reboot at this point.

Once the partition is visible, you can proceed. Use `pvs` to see if `gparted` already initialized the partition as a LVM PV; if not, run `pvcreate /dev/nvme0n1p7` to initialize it.

Then, assuming that your LVM volume group uses the default name `fedora`, run `vgextend fedora /dev/nvme0n1p7`.

Now the previously-unallocated space has been added to the volume group, and you can use it to extend existing LVs and/or create new ones as you wish.