# How can I resize my Fedora Btrfs root partition to take up Windows space with my boot partition in the way?

Tags: fedora, partition, ssd, gparted

I have a UEFI system on a laptop that's currently dual-booting Windows and Fedora 39 (KDE Plasma). I don't use Windows much, and need extra space on my Fedora partition. So, I need to shrink `nvme0n1p3` and increase the size of `nvme0n1p6`.
The problem is, my ext4 /boot partition (`nvme0n1p5`) is in the middle of those two partitions, and I'm hesitant about moving it since I don't know if I'll be able to boot afterwards (If it's safe to move it, I will).

I did also come across [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505752/how-can-i-resize-my-fedora-lvm-partition-to-be-larger-with-the-root-partition-in), but that's dealing with LVM which I don't have or know anything about. I have a live USB (GParted Live) ready that I usually use for repartitioning.

How can I decrease the size of my Windows partition and use that space for my Fedora partition?

[image: A screenshot of GParted: 260mb EFI system partition, 16mb windows recovery, 100 gb windows partition, 1gb fedora boot partition, 137 gb fedora root and home partition, unallocated 1mb, 1gb ntfs, 6mb unallocated]

Comment: BTRFS can span multiple devices, just add more devices to your BTRFS root filesystem, like so: `btrfs device add /dev/nvme0n1pX /` - I think shrinking a NTFS partition might be more difficult.

Comment: You can decrease Windows partition from Windows, but as your /boot is in between Windows partition and your BTRFS partition you probably won't be able to add any space directly. The only thing I can see there is to create another partition and add it to the BTRFS as suggested above.